# coordinating conjunctions with commas between multiple dependent clauses (rules/ usage)

Tags: commas, conjunctions

Joining multiple clauses in a single sentence using comma?
Was a question on the other site, but he's chaining multiple dependent clauses with 'which'. But in contrast with that question: using  multiple coordinating conjunctions with dependent clauses and commas?

Most grammar sites state this:

> Use commas to separate independent clauses when they are joined by any of these seven coordinating conjunctions: and, but, for, or, nor, so, yet.

But doesn't this contradict connecting dependent clauses connected with coordinating conjunctions with commas? Are there any rules?

Two  examples:

> Although there was not a cloud in the sky, **and** because Mary arrived at the bus station,
>
> partly because he was afraid of raising expectations even higher and he did not want to be distracted by interviews and adoring fans who would follow him into stores and restaurants demanding autographs and photo-opportunities, **but** mostly because he wanted to conserve his energies and concentrate on the job at hand.

Comment: The punctuation is as required. I'm not sure how a sensible sentence can be made using the first two clauses. And the second example is cluttered. 'In the woods, and also on the moors, you can sometimes spot this butterfly.' is perhaps a better example. This is a listing comma (you have a list of locative PPs). // How does a rule specifying independent clauses apply to a situation where there are dependent clauses?